# Long MAC addres in Cisco DHCP binding

Tags: cisco, dhcp

i have problem whith Cisco DHCP. On switch C6506 in "sh ip dhcp binding" table are the long MAC addres. What is the problem? The one MAC (**00.16e6.448a.e4**) have more IP addres.

```
158.195.40.46   id    ffe6.448a.e400.0100.011d.69e6.3900.16e6.448a.e4  Mar 12 2016 03:35 PM

158.195.46.201  id    ffe6.448a.e400.0100.011d.d88f.c400.16e6.448a.e4  Mar 12 2016 12:10 PM

158.195.46.202  id    0100.16e6.448a.e4  Mar 12 2016 02:09 PM

158.195.46.203  id    ffe6.448a.e400.0100.011d.d8b0.1b00.16e6.448a.e4  Mar 12 2016 02:28 PM

158.195.46.204  id    ffe6.448a.e400.0100.011d.d8b2.0500.16e6.448a.e4  Mar 14 2016 09:53 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here: https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12708241/weird-mac-address-dhcp-binding

"Okay. Please check the file /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf on the Fedora machine and add the following line to the file:

```
send dhcp-client-identifier = hardware;
```

If there are any other instances of this command in that file, please remove them - make sure this is the only one."